# Ability to perform lookup in a different file based on dropdown

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to perform a lookup in a different file based on a drop-down list.
Twist - I want the drop-down selection to create the reference to the other file.  So if I selected May 2016 from the drop-down I would have a VLOOKUP that referenced the May 2016 file in text format.

The formula would look like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,cell reference of the lookup from the drop-down, 16,0)
```

How can I insert the cell reference of the lookup from the dropdown into this formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDIRECT() and built the string for where to look up within the parentheses of the function, like `VLOOKUP(A1,INDIRECT(''''&B1&'''!'&C1),...)`.

Using similarly and logically named ranges in the different sheets might make it easier.